# Can I create a RegEx in Javascript that matches characters in order but not necessarily sequentially?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

Does anyone know a way in Javascript to efficiently check if a string contains all the characters of a substring in order, even if they are not sequential (i.e. possibly separated by other content)?

Example:

```
hasChars("turtle", "I like tu uurtle"); // true
hasChars("turtle", "t,u,r,t,l,e,"); // true
hasChars("turtle", "turtel"); // false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var patt = new RegExp(".*?t.*?u.*?r.*?t.*?l.*?e.*");
console.log(patt.test('I like tuuu ur,t,l,e,')); // true
```

Comment: "?" is not needed, because it makes no sense to have "0 or more times, 0 or 1 time".

Comment: ? is for non greedy match.or else the whole string will be consumed by .*..* is greedy ..*? is non greedy.